# GRPC connecting over TOR

Tags: java, grpc, tor, socks

Hi I am trying to connect via GRPC to a server over TOR

Currently I use the following code to connect to the clearnet version of the server but now I would like to do the same over TOR in JAVA.

```java
 OkHttpChannelBuilder builder = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
        .connectionSpec(new ConnectionSpec.Builder(OkHttpChannelBuilder.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_SPEC)
        .tlsVersions(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS.tlsVersions().toArray(new TlsVersion[0]))
        .build());


      ManagedChannel channel = builder.build();


      stub = LightningGrpc
       .newStub(channel)
       .withCallCredentials(new MacaroonCallCredential(macaroon));
```

Is it just a matter of using the onion address and port? I tried removing TLS but then I get an "UNAVAILABLE" error.

thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error that you get when you try to use the onion adress and port?

Comment: a few different one depending on my initial set up but here is a gist with the stack trace

https://gist.github.com/